# Simple search form in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a simple model (person with first and last name). I have created an admin for this model where I can add/edit/remove objects.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to use Django forms to create a simple form (without CSS and etc.) to search objects in DB? (I choose the field and the value to search) Or Django forms used only for post requests?
2. How can I add AJAX functionality to the search form, so my page stays without reloading?

Honestly, I Googled for two hours and didn`t find any information.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest "search" you can use would be using a view to return a json response. For example:

from django.http import JsonResponse

```
def SearchView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        search_query = request.GET.get('q', '')
        search_results = Game.objects.filter(title__icontains=search_query)
        return JsonResponse(search_results)
```

and then your JS would be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: YOUR_ENDPOINT,
    data : YOUR_GET_PARAMETERS,
    success: function (response) {
         // success callback
    }, 
    error: function(response) {
        // error handling
    }
});
```

Note: You can also use the [**__search__**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#the-search-lookup) field lookup for the best search results.

Comment: i vote to close the Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.